# findOrFail Laravel 8 method not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on Laravel 8 , I have tried to use findOrFail method in order to set redirection to 404 error not found instead of displaying error but it is showing this error method findOrFail not found,
this is the line of code in ProfilesController that is causing the error

```
$user = User::findOrFail($user);
```

this is the output of the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6tai.png)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like your code works fine. The issue `Php Strom` not able to identify methods.
I always use `query()` method to get autocomplete model methods

```
   $user=User::query()->findOrFail($user);
```

or you might need to install any extension which can able to identify laravel methods

Comment: thanks it has worked , yes it is with phpstorm but it affects the output